# Should I have a comma

Tags: commas, intonation

I am in the process of writing an essay. I have a sentence in which I am trying to write about my school (XYZ). The sentence reads

- This is not the XYZ students all love and adore.

Should there be a comma after the XYZ or does it read alright this way?

Comment: It is sometimes all right to drop in a comma to stand in for a missing word. This is not one of those times, as the reader easily understands the missing *that*.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is perfectly clear. A comma would not make sense after xyz.

Comment: Agree with you. A comma then would be separating two independent clauses, and that's not what the OP has in mind presumably.